# Simulate a IOS environment for test website in safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios, iphone

I'm developing an simples website using html, css/bootstrap and JS. I received feedback by Iphone user that some features not working in IOS mobile. Some Images not loading and [counter-up](http://bfintal.github.io/Counter-Up/demo/demo.html) not working too. In windows and android is working fine (chrome and Firefox). The question is, how I create a environment for simulate a IOS mobile for check how safari browser load my site? I tried install safari in windows but it not show equals execution in IOS. I think that [browsershots](http://browsershots.org/) not is a good ideia, because it works only with static content, and in the moment return 500 internal server error.

Comment: Is getting a Mac or an iPhone not an option?

Comment: If you have a mac, or access to a mac (there are subscriptions for remote options) you can run a full iPhone emulator.

Comment: Getting a Mac not is an option :(
Maybe I have access at one mac (Iphone). How works this emulation?

Comment: https://snack.expo.dev/ could help , but might be too much for simple HTML...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft BrowserStack provides a full test environment, however beyond the complimentary trial period it is not free. For errors related to pageload or reference, I would suggest you use device emulation and network throttling in a browser: Safari, Firefox, Chrome.

Some browsers are more forgiving of errors, so you may even have a typo. Is your trustworthy friend using an outdated browser while you require modern feature support? The scope of the problem seems undeserving of a bill for membership or tech support.

Comment: Addtionally I found https://appetize.io/

Comment: That looks legit, since 2015, but more like BootCamp. Check out Google Chrome Extensions and search for device emulators. There are a lot of time savers, but nothing beats the real thing. You might just run it though a linting tool or code inspector.